# Run Apache-beam pipeline job on existing google cloud VM

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am creating a python apache-beam pipeline that has google cloud SQL ingestion, so when I am deploying the pipeline, a new VM is created automatically which has no access to my google cloud SQL instance, so my job is getting failed each time. showing below error log in job logs

[image]

So I am looking for an apache-beam pipeline option with python, if I can pass any argument name as a worker(VM) name or public IP of existing VM so that job will be automatically run over the existing VM that has access to my google cloud SQL VM

So far I have checked this https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/pipeline-options it does not have any worker name argument

Please help me out

Thanks

Comment: Please can you share the error and stacktrace and a code snippet ?

Comment: You should use [a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) in order to do this kind of things. It's more secure that way.

Comment: @MazlumTosun i have updated the questions please check the error snapshot

Answer (score 0):

Probably, Dataflow workers do not have access to your Google Cloud SQL instance. Please look into [Dataflow security and permissions](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions) regarding setting up correct access for Dataflow VMs. Specifically, you need to make sure that the [Worker service account](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#worker-service-account) has access to the Cloud SQL instance.